# yarn install ember-cli fails with incompatible node engine

Tags: ember-cli, yarnpkg

My CircleCI builds started failing today and it looks like yarn is having trouble installing ember-cli. I tried locally and am suddenly getting the same error.

I recently upgraded to ember-cli 2.13.2, but I don't think that's related because builds were working after the upgrade.

Here's my console output:

```
~/code/my-app(master ✗) yarn global add ember-cli
yarn global v0.24.6
warning No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error core-object@3.1.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "=> ^4.0.0".
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Is the node version in your CircleCI environment >4 (or lts/argon or lts/boron)? You might have to specify it in your yaml file. https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/#node-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue. I was using a [Docker image](https://github.com/jribar/docker-node-phantomjs/blob/master/Dockerfile#L1) that uses the latest version of node. When node updated to 8, my Circle builds started using that. I ended up creating my own image that is pegged at version 6 and using that on Circle instead.

Answer (score 1):

What is your Node version? I've tried installing by yarn Ember CLI 1.13 project and it failed because CoreObject required versions between 4 and 7. I've downgraded Node from 8 to 7 and it worked.